# Calendar heatmap function will not execute

Tags: r

I have the following code for a calendar heatmap. I have created one previously using this code. But when I try to create another one, I enter the code and press enter but plus signs appear and I cannot execute.

```
library(ggplot2)

source("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iascchen/VisHealth/master/R/calendarHeat.R")

library(plyr)

library(plotly)

r2g <- c("#D61818", "#B5E384")

calendarHeat(heatmap1$date, heatmap1$ROI, ncolors = 2, color = "r2g", varname="30-day ROI") # here you had backquotes at the end of the line
```

heatmap1 is the name of the data.

A cut of the data is shown below

```
Row  Date      ROI
1   2010-08-17  0
2   2010-08-18  0
3   2010-08-19  0
4   2010-08-20  0
5   2010-08-21  1
6   2010-08-22  1
7   2010-08-23  1
8   2010-08-24  1
9   2010-08-25  1
10  2010-08-26  1
11  2010-08-27  1
12  2010-08-28  0
13  2010-08-29  0
14  2010-08-30  0
15  2010-08-31  0
16  2010-09-01  1
17  2010-09-02  1
18  2010-09-03  1
19  2010-09-04  1
20  2010-09-05  0
21  2010-09-06  1
22  2010-09-07  1
23  2010-09-08  0
24  2010-09-09  0
25  2010-09-10  0
26  2010-09-11  0
27  2010-09-12  0
28  2010-09-13  0
29  2010-09-14  0
30  2010-09-15  0
31  2010-09-16  0
```

I don't understand why the code will work when executed previously, but now doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: On the last line of your first code chunk, you used back quotes instead of quotes. It explain the +, because R interpret the line as unfinished.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. This "" is not back quotes? Which is quotes? And I've run this code previously and it worked, but now it doesn't for some reason.

Comment: I will edit your question, and I think it will work.

Comment: Thanks, it works!!! I'll look more closely at the code in the future. Maybe I deleted the quote and added a back quote by accident.

Comment: And sorry, there was no backquotes, but there was two different style of double quotes, but I don"t know how to name them, at least in english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a syntax error with quotes. R will propose you to continue typing a line with `+` if there is no match to `'`,`"`,`{` and`(`.

This is explained in this [pdf](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf), page 4-5.